# Duplicating elements in a ManyToMany relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-many

I have a ManyToMany relationship between Profile and ProfileExperience that is mapped as follows:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "profile_experience_relations",
    joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
    },
    inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "profile_experience_id")
    })
private List<ProfileExperience> experiences;
```

I have added localization support inside of ProfileExperience, following this [guide](https://thorben-janssen.com/localized-data-hibernate/#Different_Ways_to_Store_Localized_Data) like so:

**ProfileExperience Class**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "profileExperience", cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, orphanRemoval = true)
@MapKey(name = "localizedProfileExperiencePk.locale")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
private Map<String, LocalizedProfileExperience> localizations = new HashMap<>();
```

**LocalizedProfileExperience Class**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class LocalizedProfileExperience {

    @EmbeddedId
    private LocalizedProfileExperiencePk localizedProfileExperiencePk;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "profileExperienceId")
    private ProfileExperience profileExperience;

    private String value;
}
```

**Composite PK Class**

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
public class LocalizedProfileExperiencePk implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String profileExperienceId;
private String locale;

public LocalizedProfileExperiencePk() {
}
```

Before adding the localization, there was no duplicate entries in the responses, however - everything retrieved is now duplicated.
I can solve the issue by using a Set, however I'm curious as to why this happened. What is the explanation? Can I solve it without using a set? Am I overlooking something incredibly simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are probably using `join fetch` or an entity graph to fetch nested collections. Now, when you look at the JDBC result set, you will see that there are many duplicate result set rows. If you have a profile with 2 profile experiences, and each has 3 localizations, you will see that you have 6 (2 * 3) duplicate rows. Theoretically, Hibernate could try to retain the expected object graph cardinality, but this is not so easy, especially when multiple collections are involved. Also, for certain collection mappings it would simply not be possible to do.

So the short answer to your problem is, never use a `List` unless duplicity matters to you. In this case, you will have an order column though, so even then it would be safe to use a list.

Comment: I assume Set is the proper way to go about it anyways. Just wanted to understand as to why is it happening, even though now it perfectly makes sense (atm I have one localization - but a user can have multiple experiences - so I guess that answers it). Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `equal` method of your data class. Hibernate need it.

Comment: Implemented it everywhere. Didn't help.

Comment: Did you wrote the Hibernate documentation ?

Comment: I'm sorry? Yes I've read the related documentation if thats what you mean. However, it doesn't really provide insight into why this is happens